# Android: How to detect Phone number in all apps, add icon & click listener to trigger calling from my app

Tags: android, android-service, phone-number, calling-convention

I am looking for solution where i can detect All phone numbers in all android app, provide a feature click to call to my app user which they can make a call from my app. Since android has lot of restrictions looking for elegant solution to implement this feature. Please suggest is it possible in Andorid or not?

Comment: Check this once - > https://stackoverflow.com/q/10755994/9365212

Comment: I need to add this as click to dial features where it will detect the phone number automatically and add an icon next to it. I don't understand how it's related to contact fetching

Comment: I am not getting the feature you are asking is there any example app you have? A short video would be better

Comment: Web application has this feature please look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpGTq8T724s